How to mock an anonymous function using jest in redux-saga-test-plan
I'm trying to test a saga using redux-saga-test-plan, but faced a problem of passing an anonymous function as an argument in the "call" effect.
I know that a possible solution could be to name this () => {} function and to import it to my spec.js file, but would it be a good practice of calling it like "emptyFunction"? Is there some way to just mock it instead of naming and exporting?
Here is my saga:
export function* sagaToTest() {
    yield call(foo, () => {});
}

And a test in spec.js file
it('sagaToTest', () => {
    testSaga(Saga.sagaToTest)
      .next()
      .call(foo, () => {})
      .next()
      .isDone();
});

The error I get:
SagaTestError:
Assertion 1 failed: call effects do not match

Expected
--------
{ '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  combinator: false,
  type: 'CALL',
  payload: { context: null, fn: [Function: foo], args: [ [Function] ] } }

Actual
------
{ '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  combinator: false,
  type: 'CALL',
  payload: { context: null, fn: [Function: foo], args: [ [Function] ] } }


I've often created a const noop = () => {} function when some code I worked with needed a callback, any callback. I don't think there's any way to mock the anonymous function though, so you may just need to declare and export the "noop" function anyway. You might instead want to do a partial match, i.e. assert only only part of the payload or whatever it is you are testing. If you need more help than this though you'll probably need to [edit] your post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with and more complete details what the specific issue is.
